# LinkedIn API: incomplete updateContent (missing companyStatusUpdate) returned for certain company updates

Tags: linkedin-api

Pulling company status updates for certain companies in `linkedin` is returning incomplete `updateContent`.

We are calling:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/ID_HERE/updates:(updateKey,timestamp,updateType,updateContent,likes,updateComments)?event-type:status-update&count=100
```

For most companies this works fine. However, for certain companies, such as `linkedin id 2725179, the updates come back with part of the object details missing. The updateContent node does not have the companyStatusUpdate sub-node (where all the real details are).

Here is an example of one such update: 
https://www.linkedin.com/nhome/updates?topic=5948215794377715712

And here is JSON returned for this update:

```
{"timestamp":1418165157923,"updateComments":{"_total":0},"updateContent":{"company":{"id":2725179,"name":"Quartz"}},"updateKey":"UPDATE-c2725179-5948215794377715712","updateType":"CMPY","likes":{"_total":0}}
```

Is this a LinkedIn bug perhaps? Again, it works fine for most companies. Examples of companies that experience this issue are: techcrunch, buzzfeed, national-geographic-society, quartz-an-atlantic-media-publication.